# f# Number of elements in the set?

Tags: f#

I am trying to get the number of elements in the set, I am getting errors while compiling the following code, can someone please help me fix it:

```
let rec size S =
   match S with 
   |[] -> false
   |e::rest -> (e = S) size S.length rest
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by using head and tail coordination as follows:

```
let rec size S =
match S with 
|[] -> 0
|head::tail -> size tail + 1
```

Comment: It compiles and output as expected

Comment: While this solution works, it is not optimized because it does not use tail recursion, like this: `let rec count s num = match s with | [] -> num | head::tail -> count tail (num+1)` and then `let size s = count s 0`. Check the book “Expert F# 4.0” for more details about tail recursion.

Comment: Thank you, Kata and I have glanced at the index of the book you referred "Expert F#" and seems to be very helpful.